# Iphone 3Gs And Iphone 3

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want my app to be installed on only iPhone 3Gs and iPhone 4, running iOS 4.0 but not on iPhone 3. I did that by adding a new field in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in info.plist file called multitasking but when I submitted the file I got an email from apple saying that I used an invalid key in info.plist for the field UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities. Is there any other way for the app not to be installed on iphone 3 but only on iPhone 3Gs and iPhone 4.

Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put armv7 in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.  The original iPhone and the iPhone 3G use armv6.

Comment: Thankx for the reply. I don't have the access to iPhone 3Gs right now. I will test it on that and will let you know whether it worked or not.

Comment: The application CPU in a 3GS is armv7 architecture.