# Can you require the iPhone 3Gs (or newer) with build settings?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, build-settings

My app doesn't run on the slower hardware, but I want to support iOS 4.0, which iPhone 3G (and equivalent 2nd gen iPod touch) can run. Is there a way to prevent it from being installed via the build settings? (I'd prefer not to have to enforce it in code when the app launches.)

I thought that the VALID_ARCHS build setting might do it by removing arm6 (leaving only arm7), but I was able to install directly to a 2nd gen. iPod touch.

Comment: duplicate question [Iphone 3Gs And Iphone 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656209/iphone-3gs-and-iphone-3/3656802#3656802)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my application available on the App Store only for iPhone 3G S or faster devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or-f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I found the answer as I was posting this question, but the question "*Iphone 3Gs And Iphone 3*" isn't very searchable, so I posted this and answered it to help others in the future.)

iPhone 1, iPhone 3G are armv6. iPhone 3Gs, iPhone 4 are armv7. (iPad is armv7.)

You should set the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities setting in the Info.plist to the desired architecture (in this case armv7). You should also remove armv6 from the target build settings to reduce your compile time.)

Original answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656209/iphone-3gs-and-iphone-3/3656802#3656802).

**edit**: Apple wouldn't accept a submission with this key there. I will try this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472278/how-do-i-make-my-application-available-on-the-app-store-only-for-iphone-3g-s-or-f) and then update my answer here.

**edit 2**: Looks like [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472522/168594) worked.

FYI: I ultimately had to support the older models because my app had once been (erroneously) released. Apple's system makes you support all hardware models you have ever supported. (Which makes sense from the consumer side, which is that apps you download or buy shouldn't stop working, but stinks for me.)

Comment: next time flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @Black Frog, flag it as a duplicate if I think my question is better?

Comment: When a question is flag, other people will review it also. If your question is better, then it will stay open.

Comment: Even if yours gets closed as a duplicate, the two questions will be linked together so that someone searching for one can find the other.