# Compatible device list for iOS app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, itunes

How can I specify the compatible devices for my iphone app? I can see a compatible device list (e.g.: iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4) for several apps in iTunes but how can i set this for my own app?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656209/iphone-3gs-and-iphone-3/3656802#3656802) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you do that when submitting the app for review into the App Store.

Comment: When should that appear?
In the application loader i can select the app which is waiting for upload, give in the binary and start the upload. I can't find any device compatibility option pane anywhere...

Could you give more details?